# XML to JSON in Camel Routing not working

Tags: json, xml, apache-camel

I am trying to convert the XML message to JSON using camel router  and save it into a file. Getting the XML message from the source and saving it to destination file etc are working. But when I try to convert to JSON,  it did not work. I did not even throw any error/exception in logs. I am running on OSGI container

```
    public class CamelRouter extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
         from("file://C:/test/Sample.xml")
            .routeId("file-to-file")
               .log(LoggingLevel.INFO,"RouteID file-to-file !!!!! starting")                   
               //From XML to JSON
               .bean(CamelRouter.class, "convertXmlToJson")
               .log(LoggingLevel.INFO,"From XML to JSON !!!!! Done")
               .to("file://C:/test/JSONMessages")
               .log(LoggingLevel.INFO,"Converted Message Saved successfully");
```

The bean method to convert XML to JSON *convertXmlToJson* is shown below

```
public String convertXmlToJson(String msg) {
        log.info("NOW calling JSON conversion");
        String jsonStr = null;
        log.info("MESSAGE conversion starting : ");  //After this message nothing happened
        XMLSerializer xmlReader =  new XMLSerializer();
        log.info("MESSAGE before conversion : " + msg);
        jsonStr = xmlReader.read(msg).toString();
        log.info("JSON data : " + jsonObj.toString());

        return jsonObj.toString();
    }
```

Is anyone know why it is not executing the XMLSerializer portion. I tried this approach because the camel-xmljson's  **marshal().xmljson()** call also give me the same results. Nothing happened after the xmljson() call in my camel routing.
Things that I checked are:

- camel-xmljson feature up and running in OSGI
- Dependencies mentioned in the Apache XmlJSON website added in my pom file, xom, camel-xmljson etc.

Am I missing anything here? Please help

Comment: Can you pass the JSON string to the function and get it to convert to XML in a standalone mode?

Comment: I trying to convert XML string to JSON and I can pass XML to this function and it converts into JSON with no issues in a standalone mode. But not working in the camel routing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code route is that your [bean component](https://camel.apache.org/bean.html) handler method resides within your route builder class, plus you invoke the bean component in a way that triggers another instantiation of that route builder class.

Personally, I would move `convertXmlToJson` to an appropriate utility class. That way you reduce mix of concern in the route builder and the bean component should work fine.

Alternatively, your route **might** work, if you invoke the bean component like this:

```
  .bean(this, "convertXmlToJson")
```

Comment: I tried move the conversion method into a util class and invoke the bean like this : `.bean(new ConversionUtil(), "convertXmlToJson")` nothing happened. Do I need a @Handler annotation in my util class method?

Comment: If you add @Handler, you can remove "convertXmlToJson". Apart from that, it is not required and your invocation looks correct.

Comment: I converted XML to  POJO and then use **`marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)`** to convert to JSON . So it worked that way. But I 'd like to know how the **`marshal().xmljson()`** worked. I tried almost every instructions in Apache website and nothing worked. Is there any other trick to make that work? So then I don't have to worry about converting the XML into appropriate POJO.